# Murals in the classroom

Tags: paint

I was recently commissioned by two of my 11th grade teachers to paint them wall murals in their plain classrooms.

One is not very specific with what they want, and the other is overly specific.

The Chem. teacher wants a few of his walls painted, how long does that mean I'll have to stay after school to get that done?

Comment: My first mural took two weeks, and it was about 7ft by 6ft.

Answer (score 3):

I am not a teacher, but I too am impressed with your willingness to commit.. Do not take this as permissive, but my belief is that your education begins with your interests and the rest can be garnered in college, where you can apply yourself.

If you intend to be an artist, then this is your launching pad.

Time is always a problem when stepping into a new endeavor.  Please consider using a grid and transferring the entire image, in pencil or chalk, onto your surface.

I suspect you can google all you'll need to know about using a grid for reproducing an image onto a wall, so I won't elaborate to much here.

1. Sketch your idea or use a commercial photo.
2. Then overlay clear velum, glass, plastic, or draw a grid pattern directly onto the sketch.
3. With a chalk snap line, make a larger grid on the wall.
4. Now, imagine each square on your sketch or photo being copied onto the corresponding chalk line square on the wall, then draw it.

This will save you an enormous amount of time in every step of the mural process.  Designing, transferring, and painting can all be done on your sketch, and preparation, the key to success, is covered.

Answer (score 1):

(This is too long for a comment.)

You are not asking for opinions, but I am a teacher, and I worry that these commissions will affect your school work (staying late after school several hours a day for what could be several weeks).

They may also affect your relationships with your teachers - especially with the teacher who is being overly specific.  What happens if this teacher is not satisfied with the job you do, will you need to start again?  Will the teachers pay for your supplies as well as your time?

These are very complimentary requests, obviously you are very talented and your teachers are acknowledging that, which is wonderful. I just think these commissions would be better done over a summer break, not at the beginning of the school year.  Have you asked your parents or another trusted adult what they think?  I suggest that's a good next step if you haven't. Good luck to you, you sound like a very thoughtful and talented person.

Comment: I have made a mural over summer break, which is why they are commissioning me now. If anything, it will probably strengthen my relationship with these particular teachers.

Comment: But for the academic part, it may stunt some of my homework time, which is why my school has a program to catch up on late work and what not.